# Customer Journey Mapping

Tags: customer, journey-map

I'll be holding a customer journey mapping workshop in a few weeks.  I've identified the persona and key journey to focus on (Buying a dress). I think I should be looking at the Desktop journey and the mobile journey separately - holding 2 workshops.

Does that make sense to look at the 2 separately?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there's clear differences of user behaviour between desktop and mobile.

In 2018 mobile market share worldwide was 52.1% compared to desktop market share of 44.2%

I would personally look at the journeys in two different sessions.

Here's some more useful information about the difference between the two:

https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/mobile-usability-research-the-important-differences-from-the-desktop

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: I think you will have to accept one of the answers @Caius That is if you decided on any of them.

Answer (score 1):

For sure. The behaviours are different on each. But you'll find the journey crosses both devices and it's unlikely the whole journey will be done on just mobile or just desktop.

You need to map what the persona is doing and how s/he is doing it rather than fixating on "how would X complete the journey on mobile vs desktop"

That's my advice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's simply the customer journey, from finding, selecting, purchasing and finish, my opinion is they need to be the same, to maintain a consistent customer journey, especially for repeat visitors on multiple platforms. When you move into the customer experience stage of the process - they tend to be unique to the platform and should cater for those differences.